# Is there a way to access TFS from Visual Web Developer 2008 Express Edition?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs, express

I need to make an update for a client where I have my older dev machine still operational.  They moved my source code from SourceSafe to TFS.  My dev environment is Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2008 Express Edition, and I don't have time in the project to upgrade the solution or the dev environment.

Is there any way to get Web Developer 2008 Express to use TFS?  Or perhaps a stand-alone tool where I can do check-outs and check-ins, but still make code changes in Web Developer 2008 Express?  Or another idea...

Thanks!
Sandra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple way to do this is to install Team Explorer for the version of TFS you're using (i.e. Team Explorer 2012 for TFS 2012) You can use this as a stand alone client in the same way you used VSS. You won't be able to use the VS integration but at least you'll be able to access source control.

Comment: I downloaded and installed Visual Studio Team Explorer 2010.  But I can't find a Team Explorer shortcut anywhere.  Not sure where I went wrong.  ...  Oops, never mind.  The shortcut is inconveiently named "Microsoft Visual Studio 2010" rather than something with Team Explorer in the name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Visual Studio TFS Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b1ef7eb2-e084-4cb8-9bc7-06c3bad9148f) which will give you control of the normal source control commands through Windows Explorer.

Comment: That gives me a direction to look, even though it's for a different version.  I see other versions, so I'll hopefully find the right one and be on my way.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have VS 2008 Web Express SP1 installed, download and install below will enable you to access TFS.

1. Install [team Explorer 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16338)
2. Install [TFS 2012 compatibility GDR for VS 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=29983)

I have detailed instructions with download links here [Use TFS 2012 with Visual Studio 2008/2010 and Business Intelligence Development Studio(BIDS) 2008 R2](http://chamindac.blogspot.com/2013/02/use-tfs-2012-with-visual-studio.html)